# T-SQL Openquery - error due to space in the table name

Tags: sql-server, openquery

I have the below query that is trying to pull data from Sage 50 pervasive 13 database into SQL server using a link server.  I've been able to pull all data from all tables into SQL Server except for this one table because it has a space in the table name.

I've not been successful with anything I've changed it to. Can anyone help me get this query working?

```
select * 
from openquery(ARKSAGE,'select * from NEPHROPATHOLOGYASSO1.Budget Details')
```

When I change the above query to this:

```
select * 
from openquery(ARKSAGE,'select * from NEPHROPATHOLOGYASSO1.[Budget Details]')
```

I get this error message:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ARKSAGE" returned message "[PSQL][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][PSQL][SQL Engine]Syntax Error: select * from NEPHROPATHOLOGYASSO1.<< ??? >>[Budget Details]".
>
> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 61
> An error occurred while preparing the query "select * from NEPHROPATHOLOGYASSO1.[Budget Details]" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ARKSAGE".

Comment: Have you tried double quotes?

Comment: I changed to this:  select * 
--into [Budget Details] 
from openquery(ARKSAGE,'select * from "NEPHROPATHOLOGYASSO1.Budget Details"')   And it gave me this error (which is different than before):  OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ARKSAGE" returned message "[PSQL][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][PSQL][SQL Engine]Table name too long: NEPHROPATHOLOGYASSO1.Budget Details.".
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 60
An error occurred while preparing the query "select * from "NEPHROPATHOLOGYASSO1.Budget Details"" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ARKSAGE".

Comment: I changed to this and produced a new error  'code' select * 
--into [Budget Details] 
from openquery(ARKSAGE,'select * from ''NEPHROPATHOLOGYASSO1.Budget Details''') 'code'   error:  OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ARKSAGE" returned message "[PSQL][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][PSQL][SQL Engine]Syntax Error: select * from 'NEPHROPATHOLOGYASSO1.Budget Details<< ??? >>'".
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 60
An error occurred while preparing the query "select * from 'NEPHROPATHOLOGYASSO1.Budget Details'" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ARKSAGE".

Answer (score 0):

The `PSQL` in the error message tells me the linked server is probably running Postgresql, rather than SQL Server. Postgresql marks object names with double quotes instead of brackets. Therefore you should try this:

```
select * 
from openquery(ARKSAGE,'select * from NEPHROPATHOLOGYASSO1."Budget Details"')
```

Additionally, I'm not sure what the `<< ??? >>` text is for, but it looks a little like it's complaining about an odd unicode character in there somewhere. So look out for invisible whitespace. Or maybe it's just part of how the error message is formatted in the context of a linked Postgresql server.

Comment: Hi, This is a link server to a pervasive 13 database.    I tried the above syntax again and here is the error message that it returned.  Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 154
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "ARKSAGE".  It's connect to a 64 bit ODBC driver.  It works for all other tables except for tables with spaces in the name.  I know it's a syntax issue, just can't figure out the fix.  When I pull the data into Power BI, I do get to see the data which is another indicator it's a syntax issue.

Comment: I haven't used pervasive. You'll have to look up what it uses for marking object (table) names. Maybe it's backticks like MySQL.